# Apply GoDaddy signed SSL certificate to sub-domain

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, https, apache2

I have a site that is hosted on a dedicated GoDaddy server. Currently I have a GoDaddy signed SSL certificate which has been applied to the domain mysite.com.

In order to increase the speed of my site I have created the subdomain static.mysite.com in order to serve up the cookieless files such as images and style sheets.

The issue I now have is that there is a self-signed SSL certificate now applied to the sub-domain which causes an error in the browser when the site is viewed.

So, is there a way to apply the GoDaddy signed SSL certificate to my static sub-domain as well as the main domain? If so how would this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First at all you should check your SSL Certificate. Each SSL Certificate issued for some domains. For example StackOverflow have issued certificate for most of their domains

[image]

If you current certificate issued for your sub-domain, you could add it to subdomain in your control panel if you have it or add to Web-server configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for you assistance @Alexander T. I have provided a list of the domains below - 
cpanel.missshopuk.com, 
mail.missshopuk.com, 
missshopuk.com, 
webdisk.missshopuk.com, 
webmail.missshopuk.com, 
www.missshopuk.com

There are no wildcard symbols. does this mean I wouldn't be able to apply the certificate to the static sub-domain?

Comment: @JonathanHutchinson your certificate issued only for this domains. And couldn't be used on any other. You should issue new certificate.

Comment: Thanks again @Alexander T. I assume this would mean I would need to purchase another signed certificate in order to avoid any browser warnings?

Comment: @JonathanHutchinson you're right.